# differences between /sdcard/emulated/0 and /sdcard

Tags: android, directory, android-external-storage

I'm goig to be mad with a strange issue. If i create a folder inside my code as

```
directory_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/" + context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);

directory = new File(directory_path);
if (!directory.exists()) {
    directory.mkdirs();
}
```

a new folder is created inside /sdcard/ . If i try to print on logcat directory_path variable, the path is different: /storage/emulated/0/
and if i go to that path, i found another folder with the same name of the one created on /sdcard/ . This is a problem for me because when i try to write some data into that folder, everithing goes in the one on /storage/emulated/0 , and the other one (that is the folder i want use) remain empty. 
Why?

Comment: Did you find an answer? Seems Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() does not work on 4.2

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried reading back the data? /storage/emulated/0/ is the new path introduced in JB to support multiple users on tablet. But as long as you access external files using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` it doesn't really matter where they really reside.

Here's some additional info: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35541/why-did-sdcard-turn-into-sdcard-0-with-4-2

Comment: ok, but how can i skip this differentiation on my app? i don't want use /storage/emulated/0 , but the folder i've create for my app inside /storage

Comment: The folder under /storage/emulated/0 _is_ the storage you are supposed to use.

Answer (score 1):

> /storage/emulated/0/: to my knowledge, this refers to the "emulated
>   MMC" ("owner part"). Usually this is the internal one. The "0" stands
>   for the user here, "0" is the first user aka device-owner. If you
>   create additional users, this number will increment for each.
>
> /storage/emulated/legacy/ as before, but pointing to the part of the
>   currently working user (for the owner, this would be a symlink to
>
> /storage/emulated/0/). So this path should bring every user to his
>   "part".
>
> /sdcard/: According to a comment by Shywim, this is a symlink to...
>
> /mnt/sdcard (Android < 4.0)
>
> /storage/sdcard0 (Android 4.0+)

For more detail you can visit [stackexchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/39542/confused-by-the-many-locations-of-the-virtual-sdcard)